# Reports in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting

I am trying to use the embedded reporting tools in VS2012. I never used them before.
The report wizard force the user to select a table and I do not see any feature that allows to add or select more than one table in the same report. 
I see that there are not so many Q&A on this topic and also I have not found any decent tutorial rather then very simple samples with two columns, but lets give it some time.

Is there a way to get data from different tables of the same DB into the same report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a SQL view and then use that.  The wizard does however give you the option to choose more than one table when you create a new dataset.